# Changing TextView properties in IBAction method

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to have some text in a UITextView change color (and sometimes change text) after a button press:

I have loaded a text view in ViewController with a simple string in viewDidLoad

```
self.answer1TextView.text = questions[1];
```

The above displays just fine.

There is button next to it, which triggers the following method (also in ViewController):

```
- (IBAction)select1ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    self.answer1TextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

The problem is this: when the button is tapped, the text in the UITextView doesn't change color, and the right half of the view disappears.

I'd greatly appreciate some advice on this.  Thank you.

Comment: This should be working. Are you sure the function `select1ButtonTapped:` is called? try adding a NSLog or breakpoint to verify

Comment: I agree, and I did test the IBAction method by adding an NSLog as follows, which worked fine, after the button was tapped:  NSLog (@"%@", self.answer1.TextView.text);

Comment: ok, lets try something else...  what is printed when you put `NSLog(@"%@",[self. answer1TextView class]);` inside `select1ButtonTapped:`?

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and here is the NSLog output:  

2014-04-22 18:00:11.181 Code Fluency iPad Proto[62671:60b] UITextView

The behavior (after pushing the button) is the same as before.

Comment: I seem to have solved my problem but I'm not 100% sure of why it happened.  My UIButton is located to the right of the UITextView, and there is no overlap whatsoever in the Storyboard view. However, I found this morning that when I reduce the width of the UITextView, as if to give more margin between the two, the problem goes away and it all operates as expected. I wonder why!

Comment: For anyone's interest, I filed an Apple TSI on this; they provided a workaround which I confirmed works: 
self.answer3TextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.answer3TextView.layoutManager ensureLayoutForCharacterRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.answer3TextView.text.length)];   They confirmed it's a bug and asked me to file a bug report, which I did this morning. Interestingly, they are not crediting my TSI's even though it's a confirmed bug!